# Load/open/Incorporate IPA into app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I know this is far fetched, but I've received an IPA game from a 3rd party developer that I need some how to incorporate into an APP.

I'm doing this project for a client, and they want the game implemented in one APP. The game is developed in Flash/Air and the developer says that they can only deliver the game as IPAs.

Is there anyway that I can incorporate these IPAs into the APP, which I'm developing for my client. My Google search haven't come up with anything, so I'm guessing that it can't be done. But do i have any alternatives ?

Comment: Do you mean they are creating the app in Flash/Air and exporting them as IPA files - i.e. compiled already for iOS?  Is your problem how to convert a single IPA into an app (it already is an app... nothing to do...) or to combine multiple IPAs into a single app?  If it's the latter, I think you're stuck...  It's worth noting, however, that an IPA file is essentially a directory (right-click, show package contents), so might be worth rooting around to see what format the assets are in and whether you can combine these together into a single app somehow.

Comment: @ikuragames Thank you for your reply, yes the 3ed part developer are creating the games in flash/air and exporting them as IPA files, they told me that this is the only way they can deliver the games for IOS. My problem is that i need to combine different IPAs to a single app, so i guess that I'm stuck. But as you suggest i will look at the content and see if i can somehow get the content to work in another project. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Just to note that an IPA isn't a directory, it's a zip file. If you want to look inside, rename it with a .zip extension, unpack it and you'll get an .app file. Right click that and you can see inside with "Show Package Contents".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find an answer to this question. I did find out that you can put the game you need to use on app store and then link to it, or start it if its already on phone. I havent implemented this yet, but have from more sources that it should be possible without to much hassle.

Comment: Maybe you should link to these sources so that future people will find this question useful.

Comment: Hi. thank you for input, i never did find a online solution i talked to some people at a workshop so my knowledge is pretty much limited to what i wrote above. The programmers i talked to said they did it this way. If i find a online solution (tutorial, howto) i will of course put up a link to it. When i finish a APP with the above solution i will post some code, or maybe write a tutorial.